# Duda: ¿Cómo aplicar de formatos String en Java?

Tags: java, bluej

Quería saber cómo puedo imprimir (System.out.print()), los siguientes valores: maxPressure 345Mb, currentPressure 32Mb.

El porcentaje sería (pressure/maxPressure)*100, **Test** es un método boolean. Ejemplo con este formato:

```
MaxPressure----------34500 Mb

Current Pressure-----3200Mb

Test----------------------OK (FAIL,si falló)
```

Comment: hola, no se entiende bien tu pregunta. Quisiste decir ¿cómo aplicar DOS formatos? Y `maxPressure ` y `currentPressure` son variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entiendo que quieres tabular el mensaje que muestras pero en lugar de utilizar espacios.
Para tabular se utiliza `\t` que nos da los `"   "`
Entonces es tan sencillo como sustituir los `\t` que encontremos en la cadena por lo que queramos.
La instrucción que necesitamos es `replaceAll`
Un ejemplo sería:

```
String s ="MaxPressure\t\t34500 Mb";
String replaced = s.replaceAll("\t", "-------");
System.out.println(s);
System.out.println(replaced);
```